# How to set compose key on Centos 7 server

Tags: centos

While working on Centos 7 servers and editing files (usually via vim), I'd like to type umlauts, accent marks, etc.  How do I define a compose key for this? (Or is one already set by default?) I see similar questions and answers for various desktops, but am looking for the steps to enable this on servers.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I get for using an unfamiliar client machine! Yes, as you say, the character encoding is getting 'composed' on the client side before being sent over the network, rather than being composed on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up the compose key on your client, not the server.

It seems to work similarly to modifier keys (e.g. <kbd>shift</kbd>). The client doesn't send <kbd>shift</kbd> itself to the server, just the final (modified) glyph.